# How do I indicate 'checked' or 'selected' state for input controls in Meteor (with spacebars templates)?

Tags: meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

So I'm trying to be efficient and clean in my Spacebars templates as I work with Meteor.  But I'm stumped by the way in which checkboxes and select options are to be dealt with.  Suppose I want to have a checkbox set as checked or not depending on a flag that is in a document in one of my collections.  I don't appear to be able to do the following:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='item-{{this.item_id}}' {{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} />
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
A template tag of type BLOCKOPEN is not allowed here.
```

If I try the following options, though, they all result in the checkbox being checked even when the flag is `false`:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='item-{{this.item_id}}' checked='{{#if checked}}true{{/if}}' />
<input type='checkbox' id='item-{{this.item_id}}' checked='{{#if checked}}true{{else}}false{{/if}}' />
```

I have the same trouble with `selected` in my select options, so I end up doing something like the following to get around it, which seems verbose and error-prone:

```
<select id='option-{{this.item_id}}'>
    {{#if option_60}}
        <option value='60' selected>1 hour</option>
    {{else}}
         <option value='60'>1 hour</option>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if option_90}}
         <option value='90' selected>90 mins</option>
    {{else}}
        <option value='90'>90 mins</option>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if option_120}}
         <option value='120' selected>2 hours</option>
    {{else}}
         <option value='120'>2 hours</option>
    {{/if}}
</select>
```

Comment: Have you tried just a helper and no `{{#if}}` statement? `checked={{isChecked c=this.flag}}` I'm not sure if you can use open statements inside of tags anymore. -untested EDIT: checked one of my implementations and this is how I did it (Meteor 0.8.0+). Yes like the answer below ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use non-block helpers for placing such arguments:

```
UI.registerHelper('checkedIf', function(val) {
  return val ? 'checked' : '';
});

<input type="checkbox" {{checkedIf checked}}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the code I use to solve this problem, this should be pretty straightforward.

JS

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  checked:function(){
    // assumes that this.checked is the flag in your collection
    return this.checked?"checked":"";
  },
  options:function(){
    // store options in a helper to iterate over in the template
    // could even use http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/ in this case ?
    return [{
      value:60,
      text:"1 hour"
    },{
      value:90,
      text:"90 mins"
    },{
      value:120,
      text:"2 hours"
    }];
  },
  selected:function(value){
    // compare the current option value (this.value) with the parameter
    // the parameter is the value from the collection in this case
    return this.value==value?"selected":"";
  }
});

Template.parent.helpers({
  dataContext:function(){
    // dummy data, should come from a collection in a real application
    return {
      checked:true,
      value:90
    };
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <input type="checkbox" {{checked}}>
  <select>
    {{#each options}}
      {{! ../ syntax is used to access the parent data context which is the collection}}
      <option value="{{value}}" {{selected ../value}}>{{text}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

<template name="parent">
  {{> myTemplate dataContext}}
</template>
```

EDIT : using universal helpers as Hubert OG hinted at :

JS

```
Template.registerHelper("checkedIf",function(value){
  return value?"checked":"";
});

Template.registerHelper("selectedIfEquals",function(left,right){
  return left==right?"selected":"";
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <input type="checkbox" {{checkedIf checked}}>
  <select>
    {{#each options}}
      <option value="{{value}}" {{selectedIfEquals value ../value}}>{{text}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>  
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best, most efficient and effective way to accomplish this is to setup global template helpers, one each for determining `checked` and `selected` values. For documentation on creating global template helpers, see [this documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper).

For `checked`, I suggest implementing it in this way:

```
Template.registerHelper('isChecked', function(someValue) {
    return someValue ? 'checked' : '';
});
```

For `selected`, I suggest implementing it in this way:

```
Template.registerHelper('isSelected', function(someValue) {
    return someValue ? 'selected' : '';
});
```

With these two global template helpers implemented, you can use them in any of your templates within your application like this:

```
<template name="someTemplate">
    <input type="checkbox" {{isChecked someValue}}>

    <select>
        {{#each someOptions}}
            <option {{isSelected someValue}}>{{someDisplayValue}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```