# Meteor Select Box - mark option as selected depending on data context

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have been trying to figure out how to set the 'selected' attribute on an option within a select box and have fallen short today. Any help would be appreciated.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
When a user chooses an option and hits submit, the data saves to a new mongo document and the new entry is shown on the screen (this part works). Upon browser refresh, the state is lost (due to no selected attribute being set) and the select box goes back to the first option. I need to figure out how to set the selected state depending on the value the user has saved on that particular document. On this page there are many of the same select boxes allowing the user to choose different options for other entries.

**References (tried to implement with no luck):**

1. [Check for equality in Spacebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650658/check-for-equality-in-spacebars)
2. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected
3. [How do I indicate 'checked' or 'selected' state for input controls in Meteor (with spacebars templates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025574/meteor-js-how-can-i-indicate-checked-or-selected-in-the-templating-system)

**select box template:**

```
<template name="tEdit">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="controls">
    {{> fFEdit}}
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**select box option template:**

```
<template name="fFEdit">
  <select class="form-control" name="fFSelect">
    {{#each fFSelect}}
      <option value="{{fId}}">{{fF}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

**setting data context**

```
Template.fFEdit.helpers({
  fFSelect: function() {
    var fFArray = [
      { fF: "foo", fId: 0 },
      { fF: "bar", fId: 1 },
      { fF: "buzz", fId: 2 }
    ];
    return fFArray;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer to my problem, though this is what I came up with to add the selected attribute to the saved option. I welcome anyone else with a better/Meteor solution for this.

When the user clicks the edit link, I find the inputs that need to be updated and assign the values onClick. Ideally I'd rather have this already done on pageLoad, though feel that that solution may impact the initial pageLoad time.

```
Template.tItem.events({
  'click .edit-t-item': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $editTWrapper = $(e.currentTarget).next('.edit-t-wrapper');
    $editTWrapper.find('[name=tNEdit]').val(this.tName);
    $editTWrapper.find('[name=fFSelect]').val(this.fFId);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want state to be persisted across browser refreshes, you should be able to either fetch it from the server or from something like the [Meteor Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).

The second thing you'd need is a helper to get the selected state. Conveniently, Meteor makes the data context available under `this` (for an each loop, this context is an individual item).

```
Template.userEdit.helpers({
  userSelected: function() {
    if(this.id === Session.get("selectedUserId")) {
      return "selected";
    }
  }
});
```

This assumes you've set the Session variable previously with something like `Session.set("selectedUserId", user._id)`.

Then in your template:

```
<template name="userEdit">
  <select class="form-control" name="userSelect">
    {{#each users}}
      <option {{userSelected}}>{{username}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

(Note: The selected state can not actually be seen by inspecting the DOM with an element inspector.)